# how to pass parameters to jetty service

Tags: java, windows-services, jetty

When i run jetty in the following way:

```
set PROJECT_HOME=%CD%
start java  -Dproject.home="%PROJECT_HOME%" -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=stop -jar start.jar etc/jetty-logging.xml etc/jetty.xml
```

i am able to use parameter **PROJECT_HOME** in *mycontext.xml*:

```
SystemProperty name="project.home" default=""
```

Is there any way to pass **PROJECT_HOME** to *mycontext.xml* when I run jetty from *Jetty-Services.exe*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows Service Wrapper.

I think you can configure this in the jetty-service.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djetty.home=../projectHome
```